# How to force heroku to use JSON/ext over JSON/pure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, heroku, resque

I've hit a stumbling block and I'm not sure how to proceed. I'm trying to get resque working with redis to go on heroku, I have it all working locally, but when I push to my staging environment and try to queue a job I get the following exception:

TypeError: wrong argument type JSON::Pure::Generator::State (expected Data)

On my local machine the JSON encoder is Ext, but when I deploy it's Pure. I figured this was the source of the problem and when I forced my local environment to use the pure encoder I hit the same issue. I've tried to force the use of Ext by using both a preinitializer and trying to :require it using the Gemfile and in my rails environment.rb.

When I log into heroku console and require 'json/ext' it returns false.

I'm stumped as to how to fix this and have raised a heroku support ticket, but figured someone here might have run into the same problem.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out when I forced everything to use json/pure it all worked.  Weird, but there you go.